# When can the Second Derivative test for functions of 2 variables not be used?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

For this test $d = f_{xx}(a,b)f_{yy}(a,b)-f_{xy}(a,b)^2$
if $d>0$ then $(a,b)$ is a max or min.

This can be determined if $f_{xx}$ or $f_{yy}$ is negative or positive because they will both be either negative or positive.

if $d<0$ then $(a,b)$ is a saddle point

if $d=0$ inconclusive

If $f_{xx(}a,b)$ and $f_{yy}(a,b)$ are real numbers that are not $0$ then can the max, min, or saddle point be determined without this test by just examining the second partials of $x$ and $y$.
For example is $f_{xx}(a,b)$ and $f_{yy} (a,b)$ are both negative numbers then could $(a,b)$ be anything but a maximum?